# How to wake up kernel process in the waiting queue

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a hard time understanding how Wait Queues works in the Linux kernel, I tried to implement a simple example of Wait Queues but with an unsuccessful attempt. I know that when using `wait_event_interruptible(w, condition)`, the process is put to sleep (`TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`) until the condition evaluates to `true`.

I don't understand how these both things works.

- The `condition` is checked each time the `waitqueue wq` is woken up.
- `wake_up` has to be called after changing any variable that could change the result of the wait condition.

**How can we wake up the process after it put to sleep exactly?**

This code goes to sleep and never wakes up.

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

// Declare the wait queue with a macro
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wait_queue_t);

// Variables
int i = 5;

static void change_val(int *i)
{
    *i = 4;
}

static int __init sys_module_init(void)
{
    wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue_t, (i == 4)); // Sleeping until "i" is equal to 4
    change_val(&i); // Changing the value of "i"
    wake_up(&wait_queue_t); // Waking up the wait_queue
    
    return 0;
}
// ... other kernel module code
```

Comment: What's the behavior you get when running this code?

Comment: @wxz It never wakes up, just continues to sleep.

Comment: I haven't played with this code specifically myself, but it seems to me that the wake_up function is something that needs to be called by another process/function invocation than the function that is sleeping. As in, if you put yourself to sleep, you can't revive yourself two lines later...if you're still sleeping. Maybe look at [this guide](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144) for help? Specifically see how they have the wait_event_interruptible when the driver is read and separately have the wake_up when the driver is written to.

Comment: @wxz Thanks. `wake_up function needs to be called by another process/function invocation than the function that is sleeping.`, so, according to you the function itself is sleeping and not the process? Also, how can we call another function if the function that we are calling from is sleeping?

Comment: The guide I linked is a device driver, when you read from it (i.e. use `cat /dev/your_device`) the read function is invoked. When you write to it (say `echo "test" > /dev/your_device`), the write function is invoked. Two separate function invocations, one which can wake the other. If this is a process, then another process would be needed to wake up the sleeping process. I imagine you could use `fork` to create two processes, one that puts itself to sleep, then the other changes the variable and wakes up the other.

Comment: You can't. If a process calls `wait_event_interruptible`, it will sleep. Until some _other_ process [or interrupt service routine] wakes it up with a call to `wake_up`. And, hopefully, the condition expression has been met [or a signal has occurred]. Otherwise, the macro will loop. There are `*_timeout` versions. Look at `linux/wait.h` as these are _macros_.

Comment: @wxz And Craig Estey. Oh, now I understand, thanks!

Comment: BTW, they are paired. If you use `wait_event_interruptible`, you probably want: `wake_up_interruptible` [_not_ just `wake_up`].